# How to connect an observable with a mat-select (selectionChange) event

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my app, a document is a json file with several properties in that json file. I have a document observable

```
selectedDocument$ = this.store.selectedDocument$.pipe(tap(document => {console.log(document)}));
```

which is being insert into the template in this manner:

```
*ngIf="{ sd: selectedDocument$ | async } as asyncData"
```

With a mat-select I am selecting which specific part of that document to take and do some things, that I need to do. For selecting which part I am to look at I use this in the template:

```
<mat-select
    [formControl]="graphDatasetsFormControl"
    (selectionChange)="onGraphDatasetChange($event)"
    ngDefaultControl
>
```

and then I am getting that event handled in the code like this:

```
onGraphDatasetChange(e) {
        console.log(e.value);
}
```

the `e.value` contains the property that I need to extract from the document from the first tap. How can I connect these two and get a the value , when the select changes?

Comment: if the mat-select is under the *ngIf you can pass a second argument to your function: `(selectionChange)="onGraphDatasetChange($event,asyncData)"`, else you can use your pipe(tap) to store in a variable the data: `this.store.selectedDocument$.pipe(tap(document =>{this.document=document})`

Comment: @Eliseo first solution looks great! For the second solution, I actually knew I could save that data on a property, but I was trying to avoid that. Following the declarative programming paradigm. Your advice is much appreciated.